# Pagebreaks between environments rather than within it

Tags: environments, page-breaking, exercises, columnbreak

I use the `exercise` package to produce exercise sheets composed of series of small questions.

As I use a two columns layout, I often encounter page/column breaks, and sometimes it cuts the exercise at an ugly place: see Exercise 3 in the following MWE. A break just after Exercise 2 should be better.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
A small sentence to describe the context of this small exercise.
\Question{Please fill this table:}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\Question{Can you answer this question?}
\Question{And this one?}
\Question{And this other one ?}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}
 \lipsum[1]
\Question{Can you answer this question?}
\Question{And this one?}
\Question{And this other one ?}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}
A small sentence to describe the context of this small exercise.
\Question{Please fill again this table:}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\Question{Can you answer this question?}
\Question{And this one?}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}
 \lipsum[1]
\Question{Can you answer this question?}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

How can I preferentially put breaks *between* environments rather than *within* it? Note that I don't want to totally forbid page/column breaks.

The [`\nopagebreak[number]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2210728/8572976) seem suitable to me, but how to apply it to a whole environment such as the `Exercise` one?

Comment: `\nopagebreak` is designed to work only at the specific place/line of the document where it is used. There's also the `samepage` environment to keep a block of text together on one page/column. Have you tried wrapping that around your exercises?

Comment: @siracusa : I didn't know this environment, thanks for the tip! This seems to work to group the content of an exercise, but the title (« Exercise 3 » here) remains separated from the body of the exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopagebrk) a solution using the `\needspace` command, from the `needspace` package:

> [Its] argument tells what space is needed. If the space isn’t
>   available, the current page is cleared, and the matter that needs to
>   be kept together will be inserted on the new page.

And here comes my modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{needspace}

\let\oldExerciseHeader\ExerciseHeader
\def\ExerciseHeader{\needspace{4\baselineskip}\oldExerciseHeader} % Redefine Exercise header to include needspace command. 

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
A small sentence to describe the context of this small exercise.
\Question{Please fill this table:}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\Question{Can you answer this question?}
\Question{And this one?}
\Question{And this other one ?}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}
 \lipsum[1]
\Question{Can you answer this question?}
\Question{And this one?}
\Question{And this other one ?}
\end{Exercise}

% \begin{samepage}
\begin{Exercise}
A small sentence to describe the context of this small exercise.
\Question{Please fill again this table:}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
 A & B & C & ??\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\Question{Can you answer this question?}
\Question{And this one?}
\end{Exercise}
% \end{samepage}

\begin{Exercise}
 \lipsum[1]
\Question{Can you answer this question?}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

The length retained (`4\baselineskip`) can be changed to fit your needs, of course.

[image: result]